# how to navigate to a web page on a button click in windows phone application development

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I am working on my first app in windows phone application. On clicking an image i want to navigate to a web site but on a different page in my application. What i did till now is:

```
private void Image_Click1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page2.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    WebBrowserTask webBrowserTask = new WebBrowserTask();
    webBrowserTask.Uri = new Uri("http://www.google.com");
    webBrowserTask.Show();
}
```

Now if i do it in this way i get some problems in `webBrowserTask.Show()`. Due to this method my application doesnot run. HOwever if i remove the navigationservice line it navigates to the web sute but on the same page... Please help....Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well in your code, before the web page gets loaded it navigates to Page2

what best you can do is

remove the WebBrowserTask code and

Override the OnNavigated to event of Page2 and there, write the code for WebBrowserTask.

This would make your web page rendered on page2

Somewhat like this.

```
  protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
           WebBrowserTask webBrowserTask = new WebBrowserTask(); webBrowserTask.Uri = new Uri("http://www.google.com"); webBrowserTask.Show(); 
        }
```

Comment: but will this navigate to another page in my application? moreover i am writing this code in button click

Comment: in your code you are first making a navigation, then you are going for a webbrowsertask. The root of the error you are getting is this. If you remove webbrowsertask coding from there and keep navigation code as it  is, it wont happen. So, just Remove that code and implement the code given in my answer. you will get your work done :)

Comment: its working fine now....thanks for your help.....can u please suggest if i can put a cancel button in the page where the web site is opening so that i can come out of the site

Comment: you can use phones back button to get back to the page where from you have made the navigation to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a global WebBrowserTask in app.xaml.cs, after that you can assign the url to it in click event handler. then navigate to page2, after that use the global WebBrowserTask there.